# How to filter same name controls using JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a tabcontainer control which contains 5 tabs. Each tab contains a usercontrol if i create a button e.g btnControl1 in usercontrol of tab1 & in second tab's usercontrol i  create a button with the same name btnControl1. How can i filter tab1's usercontrol's btnControl1 & tab2's usercontrol's btnControl1 using Jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter using the tab name and the control, e.g.

```
var btn1 = $('#tab1 #btnControl');
var btn2 = $('#tab2 #btnControl');
```

However, it's still best practice to try and avoid having the same ID's on the same page.

ASP.NET often changes the ID from what you set it server side, so you can use the ClientID property (if using ASP.NET 4) to give a unique ID to each button.

Good article about ClientID - https://web.archive.org/web/20211020203215/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031710-1.aspx

Comment: I am using ASP.net 4.0 only. How to use ClientID property plz give e.g

Comment: Updated question with link to an article that discusses using ClientID.

Comment: In this article the ClientIDMode is explained. It allows the developer to specify how ASP.NET will treat the IDs of the controls http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article838-aspnet-40-manipulate-clientid-using-clientidmode-.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to distinguish the buttons or get both. In the case when you want to get both buttons you can use `$("#btnControl1:contains")`. This will return you all the controls that have in their name "btnControl1". The reason is that ASP.Net will generate different id's for the controls that use the same name.